# How can I use pyspark in zeppelin?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I installed spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz in ubuntu.

I set the zeppelin-env.sh like below.

```
    export PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python
    export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/jin/spark/python
```

So I try to use pyspark in the zeppelin notebook.

```
    %spark.pyspark

    print(2+2)
```

There are errors occurred in zeppelin notebook.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_2(SparkInterpreter.java:380)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:369)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:144)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:817)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.getSparkInterpreter(PySparkInterpreter.java:546)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.createGatewayServerAndStartScript(PySparkInterpreter.java:206)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.open(PySparkInterpreter.java:160)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:482)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't know why these errors are occurred.

Would you give me some advice?

Comment: What is your zeppeiln version?

Comment: My zeppelin version is zeppelin-0.7.0-bin-all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Jupiter without the Spark Environment ?

And equally can you use Spark without the Jupiter Environment ?

Comment: Thank you for replaying but I use a zeppelin notebook. Not a Jupyter.